# how to compare two div text?

Tags: html, text, compare

I want to make code under code using jquery.

How do I do this?

```css
ex{
  color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="exam">
  hi
  hello
  world!
  </div>

<div id="div2" class="exam">
  hi
  hello
  <ex>papper
  bro</ex>!
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you be more clear on your question?

Comment: I want to compare 2 strings. One is div1's contents, the other is div2's contens. after compare, I want to color the character of the div 1 and div 2  like eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3CRA/77/)

I modified the default **Javascript Diff Algorithm  By John Resig**. You can still customize it.

So you can differentiate with this:

```
$('#div1').diffString($('#div2').html());
```

Comment: It is a little lacking in my opinion. because It does not check insert and delete. but Thank you for your comments. ^_^